# Adding a nickname to an R package?

Tags: r, r-package

When developping an R package, is it possible to add a nickname to a certain version?

How would this be added in the DESCRIPTION file?

That cannot be in the version, as only numbers are accepted. It could of course be in the description, but it would not be a real metadata.

Comment: What exactly would you do with this nickname? There aren't any standard functions for working with packages that accept nicknames anywhere. You could show a message when the package is attached to tell the user what nickname is running, but that would be managed outside the DESCRIPTION file.

Comment: @MrFlick it would fill the exact same purpose than the R versions nicknames that we see upon opening R and with ``R.Version()$nickname``, that is, absolutely nothing beyond branding the version, keeping the team united, and having good time brainstorming the next nickname. For all these reasons, I think nicknames matter.

Comment: Nothing like that currently exists for packages. If you want to suggest that to the R developers, the r-package-devel mailing list is probably a good place to do that https://stat.ethz.ch/mailman/listinfo/r-package-devel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a field to the `DESCRIPTION` file for this:

```
Package: coolpkg
Nickname: Coolest Nickname Ever
Version: 0.1.0
```

After installing your package you can then get the nickname back like this:

`packageDescription("coolpkg")[["Nickname"]]`

FYI I think CRAN has standards around what can go in the `DESCRIPTION` file, just something to keep in mind if that's what you're working towards.

Alternatively, you could just save the nickname as a data object in the package.

Comment: Thanks to the R developper team for adding this metadata.